# How do I use values_at in a before_save method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to pass the year, month, and date from `:date` to `:start_time` but I'm getting the following error: **undefined method `values_at'**. I think I don't have the syntax quite right in my method:

```
def set_start_time_date
  self.start_time = date.values_at( :year, :month, :day )
  return true
end
before_save :set_start_time_date
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Edit: In my migration, `:date` is t.date and `:start_time` is t.datetime

Comment: `date.to_time` didn't work for you?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, or maybe I didn't explain well enough. I don't need the time on `:date` but I'm trying to set the `:start_time` date to automatically fetch the date from `:date`.

Comment: What does the local variable `date` reference in the scope of this method? If it's nil there is your issue.

Comment: @rudolph9 it seems to be passing the value correctly. In the form I set the date to 2012-10-24 and my error message reads: **undefined method `values_at' for Wed, 24 Oct 2012:Date**. That makes me think it's not receiving nil

Comment: So `date` is a string object correct?  And you want to be able to treat it like a hash and have the method `values_at` return an array with the values specified in according order?

Comment: @rudolph9 I don't think `:date` is a string object. It's defined as :date in my migration so it should be a date object? I'd like to pass the value of the `:date` (year, month, day) to `:start_time` the best way possible, and I thought the `values_at` would do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
def set_start_time_date
  self.start_time = DateTime.strptime("#{date.strftime} #{event_start.strftime('%H:%M:%S')} #{event_start.zone}", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z")
  return true
end
```

**UPDATE:**

If you have `Date` and `Time` object you can create `DateTime` without converting to string:

```
def set_start_time_date
  self.start_time = DateTime.new(date.year, date.month, date.day, event_start.hour, event_start.min, event_start.sec, event_start.zone)
  return true
end
```

Comment: This technically saved to the DB, but didn't display correctly anywhere throughout my app. I need to keep `:start_time` in a datetime format

Comment: Use strftime on this column anywhere in your app. For example start_time.strftime('%H:%M'). Or tell me how you want to display it.

Comment: I changed #{Time.now to #{event_start and this seems to work. And the strftime formats were already implemented elsewhere in the app so they're working correctly too. Would you mind explaining the process a bit? Specifically, why converting it to a string works whereas keeping both attributes in their native (date) formats doesn't.

Comment: I am updated my answer, you are right if you have Date and Time objects you can use it to create DateTime.

Comment: In previous comment you tell about "I changed #{Time.now to #{event_start"

Comment: is it possible to add time zone info to this?